# How to access properties of a FileReference Object in fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Below you see the debug for an object of type FileReference in fluid. In fluid the debug looks like this: `<f:debug>{fileReference}</f:debug>`

The question is how do I access the properties highlighted in green, being `width`, `height`, and `hovertext`.

The original file is an image, so `width` & `height` are default T3 properties, `hovertext` has been added by my extension with it's own getter/setter.

I tried the following:

```
{fileReference.width}
{fileReference.mergedProperties.width}
{fileReference.originalResource.width}
```

No luck so far, what is the right way to access the values in `mergedProperties`?

Many Thanks

Florian

[image: TYPO3 fluid Debug]

Comment: Are you sure your file class extends from the default class?

Comment: Pretty sure yes, but even though, should that have any effect on the standard width & height attribute for images? Those have been added by the core team themselves, those should work in any case or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `f:debug` shows something similar to the `var_dump` function, so the properties of an object. In fluid you can only access the getter functions or if it is an array the values of the array. So if you write something like `{fileReference.mergedProperties}` the method `getMergedProperties()` is called if it is present.

Knowing that you can look inside the `sysext/core/Classes/Resource/FileReference.php` File and see what getters it has. We can quickly find the `public function getProperties()` that returns the merged properties you marked, so the right solution should be this:

```
{fileReference.properties.width}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much, that was incredibly helpful. You not only provided the solution to my problem, but know I know how that works and can look for myself the next time.

Comment: This answer and the question should be upvoted by anyone who sees it. It completely explains the details about the DebuggerUtility and Fluid (internally, Extbase) variable access. If you want to know *every* last detail about how Fluid accesses any variable, you may find https://vimeo.com/169551666 informative. But do upvote this answer and question!

Comment: Once again, this is obligatory information that should be explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Just a note to people who don't get this immediately (including me): You can do this exact thing for other classes. If you i.e. want to get the title or the width of the file instead of filereference, just use  {file.properties.width}