# TCA property not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have in my TYPO3 an object called Location where I store informations about a city, including a pdf file.
In the backend I can upload a pdf without problem, but when I try to display it, I get NULL. The value of 'pdf' in the database is not NULL, but when I debug `<f:debug>{location}</f:debug>` I get pdf => NULL !!!

Here is my TCA/LOCATION :

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_locations_domain_model_location'] = array(
    'ctrl' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_locations_domain_model_location']['ctrl'],

....
    'columns' => array(
...
        'pdf' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:locations/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_locations_domain_model_location.pdf',
            'config' => array (
                'type' => 'group',
                'internal_type' => 'file',
                'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
                'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'],
                'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/pics',
                'show_thumbs' => 1,
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1
            )
        ),
...
```

The Getter and Setter should be fine in ***typo3conf/ext/locations/Classes/Domain/Model/Location.php*** :

```
/**
 * Returns the pdf
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $pdf
 */
public function getPdf() {
    return $this->pdf;
}

/**
 * Sets the pdf
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $pdf
 * @return void
 */
public function setPdf(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $pdf) {
    $this->pdf = $pdf;
}
```

You can see the debug gives pdf=> NULL from below:

[image: See here]

My pdf column is not empty :

[image: See here]

Did I miss something ??

***UPDATE :***
After the answer of Pavin, I can see something in PDF, but I can't get the name of the file in href tag , maybe I need to change something after the new answer.
I can see things changed in the Database, the pdf field now is boolean. that's why maybe I get pdf0.originalResource NULL, but in the backend I can upload files and see then after save and refresh !!!:

[image]

```
        <p><f:translate key="tx_locations_domain_model_location.downloadpdf" /> <a class="download" target="_blank" title="Initiates file download" href="{location.pdf.originalResource.publicUrl}"><f:translate key="tx_locations_domain_model_location.here" />..</a></p>
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

my new Model/Location.php

```
/**
     * pdf
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $pdf = NULL;

...
/**
     * Returns the pdf
     *
     * @return string $pdf
     */
    public function getPdf() {
        return $this->pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the pdf
     *
     * @param string $pdf
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPdf($pdf) {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }
```

My TCA/Location.php

```
'pdf' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:locations/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_locations_domain_model_location.pdf',
            'config' => array (
                'type' => 'group',
                'internal_type' => 'file',
                'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
                'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'],
                'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/pics',
                'show_thumbs' => 1,
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below TCA configuration for `Doc` types records. also add Getter and Setter methods in modle file.

```
'pdf' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ext_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:label_key.files',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'pdf',
        array('minitems' => 0,'maxitems' => 10),
        'pdf,doc,docx'
    ),
),
```

For **Model.php** files.

```
    /**
     * pdf
     *
     *@var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     */
    protected $pdf;
```

**initStorageObjects** Methods :

```
    protected function initStorageObjects() {
        $this->files = new ObjectStorage();
        parent::initializeObject();
    }
```

**Getter And Setter Method**:

```
   /**
     * Returns the pdf
     *
     * @return ObjectStorage
     */
    public function getPdf() {
        return $this->pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the pdf
     *
     */
    public function setPdf($pdf) {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }
```

See attached image for pdf name. Please add pdf title. For Pdf title you can use `{location.pdf.title}`
[image]

Comment: This didn't work, I don't even see anymore the pdf uploader in the Backend

Comment: I updated my Location.php as you said, it didn't work, now I get in the BackEnd "Unknown type: " !!

Comment: In **initStorageObjects** methos like $this->pdf = new ObjectStorage();

Comment: I don't have Model.php, Maybe you mean Model.phpt or Model/Location.php ? Anyway I tried them both and didn't work, in the frontend I get alwayspdf=>NULL

Comment: After add this changes you need to once install / un-install extension. you did it?

Comment: (See my UPDATE) I reactivated the exension (because somehow I can't download it), but I see the upload imterface changed in my BE (that's fine), and I can't get the filename with the new changes, I used before **href="{location.pdf.originalResource.publicUrl}"**

Comment: This I did, but in the location table, the pdf row is 1 or 0, how can I have the file name in <a href="????">clic to download</a> ??

Comment: I see the same thing as you in BE, and it is ok, but my problem was always in the front end to get the name of the file, before pdf was NULL, now pdf is not NULL but location.pdf.originalResource is NULL

Comment: in Location Table pdf value always  0 and 1. if you have add pdf then it's 1 othervies 0. You can use **<a href="{location.pdf.originalResource.publicUrl}" >Download</a>**. also in template file if you need display pdf name then add  **{location.pdf.title}**. if you have added pdf title then it's display

Comment: You can see my second debug picture,  originalResource is NULL and there is no title proprtie.

Comment: Can you come to chat please ? with send you more screenshots, better then drop them all in the post

Comment: Yes You right **originalResource** always display null. But if you can use **{location.pdf.originalResource.publicUrl}** in template file. after check frontend and inspect element. pdf path is alrady asign in href tag

Comment: I checked, it is NULL :/ also debug **<f:debug>{location.pdf.originalResource.publicUrl}</f:debug>** gives NULL !!!

Comment: Okay. in Location table pdf fields data type set int. after extension install / un-insatll and check now

Comment: For both **varchar** or **int** it is the same, **location.pdf.originalResource** is NULL :/

Answer (score 0):

You use `group` as the type for saving the file in the TCA, so the property `$pdf` in your model must be `string` and not `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference`

FileReference only work for FAL (File Abstraction Layer)

Comment: I changed $pdf type to string in Model/Lation.php and I get {location.pdf} NULL in the frontEnd, but it is still fine in the Backend

Comment: Did you clear the system cache after changing the property? Also did you update your getter and setter?

Comment: If you already did change your TCA to use FAL, than you need to use FileReference. Here is a detailed answer on what you can do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135241/how-to-access-properties-of-a-filereference-object-in-fluid/40141724#40141724 . The name of the file would be `{location.pdf.properties.name}`

Comment: Still NULL, see my **UPDATE2**

Comment: What typo3 version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 6.2.9

Comment: Try clearing the table `cf_extbase_reflection` and clear the cache afterwards.